# For what $n$ is $\frac{p^n\cdot x-1}{p+1}$ integer, given $\lvert x\rvert_p=1$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

> For what $n$ is $\dfrac{p^n\cdot x-1}{p+1}$ integer, given $\lvert x\rvert_p=1$?

Where $\lvert x\rvert_p$ is inverse of the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$ (i.e. the p-adic absolute value)

I have for $p=2$ that:

Where $x\equiv3\pmod{6}$ there are no solutions.

Where $x\equiv 1\pmod{6}$, then $n\equiv 0\pmod{2}$.

Where $x\equiv 5\pmod{6}$, then $n\equiv 1\pmod{2}$.

---

For general $p$:

Where $x\equiv0\pmod{p}$ there are no solutions.

I can't see how complex the rest of the general form is likely to be, if attainable.

Comment: Is x in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @StevenGrigsby thank-you for looking. I guess the more general the better but Kenny's answer does all I actually need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{p^n\cdot x-1}{p+1} = \frac{p^n\cdot x-(-1)^n \cdot x}{p+1} + \frac{(-1)^n \cdot x-1}{p+1} = x \frac{p^n-(-1)^n}{p+1} + \frac{(-1)^n \cdot x-1}{p+1}$$

So it is determined by the parity of $n$.